# to always start restart code after fatal error?

Tags: node.js

I have a code in node js, I'm using forever start to start the code, I was wondering if it restarts the code and if not how to configure? gave a fatal error and he did not reset the code ..
follow the error

```
read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: I put it in english, sorry

Comment: I am also getting the same error after connecting my Nodejs application with a remote database while remote database connection establishing very well with workbench.